# Alternate Solution to Python Linked List method 'Get Element From Position' Is not Working

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm having an issue with the code that I'm testing on a Udacity compiler for a course. I'm trying to test a solution that is similar to the answer provided by the course but it gives me an error. The challenge is to provide a method that returns an element in a certain position within a linked list. Here is my solution:

```
def get_position(self, position):
        counter = 1
        current = self.head             

        while counter <= position:
            if current != position:
                print "Counter %s" %counter
                print "Position %s" %position     
                current = current.next
            else:
                print "Success"
                return current
            counter += 1

        return None
```

After testing this solution out, I'm getting the error, namely: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'`

Now the solution provided by the challenge is this one below:

```
def get_position(self, position):
        counter = 1
        current = self.head
        if position < 1:
            return None
        while current and counter <= position:
            if counter == position:
                return current
            current = current.next
            counter += 1
        return None
```

It looks fairly similar to my solution except that I don't compare the variable current since I feel it's redundant and I've also changed the comparison between counter and position to check if its not equal. I'm getting wrong results too when I try out some test cases.

For example, if I test this out: `print ll.get_position(3).value` where ll is the linkedlist class and I print out some variables, I get

```
Counter 1
Position 3
Counter 2
Position 3
Counter 3
Position 3
```

but not the "Success" string which I expect when the counter and position are equal. Why is this the case?

Comment: How can you get a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'` error if your code never even tries to access a `.value` attribute anywhere?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I believe the 'print ll.get_position(3).value' test case which I provided requests for a value to be returned and returning 'current' variable from my code should do it as expected. Instead it gives this error. When I tried the actual solution by the challenge, it gives me 3.